# How to plot binomial generalized mixed effects model with 95% CI error bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, mixed-models

I have just finished model selection and have a binomial generalized mixed effect model that I would like to graph in ggplot. For context, I did model selection to see what factors can predict attendance. The factors I looked at were Day (ranging from -30 to -2, relative to Day 0), Sex (M or F), and a Sex:Day interaction. I also included several random effects, including AgeClass (young, medium, or old-aged), Year (Calendar year, 2014-2018), and Plastic (individual ID, used to correct for repeated samples).

Here is my relevant information and code:

Data (csv file): https://ufile.io/o0ns03ho

Code:

```
library(lme4)

data <- read.csv("test2.csv")

m1 <- glmer(
  Attendance ~ Day + Sex + Sex:Day + (1|AgeClass) + (1|Year) + (1|Plastic), 
  data = data, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)

summary(m1)
```

Based on the estimate values for the betas, I expect the graph to look something like this:

[image: Example graph]

I expect males to attend more frequently than females, and for the slope of males to be different than females. I would also like to be able to plot 95% CI for males and females, as shown in the drawing by the dashed lines above and below the solid line for each sex.

I only have basic knowledge in ggplot, so any and all advice is helpful. I don't need EXACT code, but a push in the right direction in terms of functions relating to the model and ggplot would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: see also: `ggeffects` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sjPlot::plot_model()` is an out-of-the-box function for plotting model results:

```r
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)

# example model
m1 <- glmer(
  r2 ~ Anger * Gender + btype + situ + (1|id) + (1|item), 
  family = binomial,
  data = VerbAgg
)

plot_model(m1, type = "pred", terms = c("Anger", "Gender"))
```

[image]

The result is a ggplot, so you can tweak it using ggplot2 functions. e.g.,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

plot_model(m1, type = "pred", terms = c("Anger", "Gender")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Trait Anger", y = "Predicted Probability of Response", title = NULL) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was awesome! I see it added 95% CI by default, but you can add the argument ci.lvl to specify. Quick question: what exactly does the "pred" option do in the function? Does that relate to the type of model I'm using? Also, is this how most people graph regression models, or only mixed effects models?

Comment: When `type = "pred"`, it will plot model-predicted values at different levels of the predictors specified in `terms`. In the case of a binomial model, these will be predicted probabilities. Other options are described under the `type` argument in [`?sjPlot::plot_model`](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html). And yes, `plot_model()` is an equally good option for fixed effects models.

Comment: Would you be able to look at my most recent post about the error bars produced by this function? I'm having trouble conceptualizing them given the summary output of the model I'm using, and I would appreciate your help given your knowledge about the plot_model function!